# Excel Mapping with multiple matches

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, vlookup

my knowledge of excel extends to most types of advanced formulas. I don't know much about how to use VBA or macros. I have a problem which I'm struggling to solve using formulas. I have a sheet with two columns that looks like this:

```
x1  y1
x1  y2
x1  y3
x1  y4
x2  y2
x2  y3
x2  y4
x3  y1
x4  y2
```

And I'm trying to map these onto a a sheet like this:

```
    y1  y2  y3  y4
 x1 1   1   1   1
 x2 0   1   1   1
 x3 1   0   0   0
 x4 0   1   0   0
```

I usually try to apply a vlookup solution to such problems, but I can't figure out how to get vlookup to work given that the x values appear multiple times in the first table, and vlookup will always just stop at the first appearance.

Please let me know how to best approach solving this problem.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Use countifs().

Comment: But a pivot table may be better suited.

Comment: @ScottCraner can you elaborate? I tried using countif with a vlookup nested within it, but could not figure out how to catch multiple matches this way.

Comment: no vlookup, just countifs():  `=COUNTIFS(A:A,$D2,B:B,E$1)`

Comment: @ScottCraner this solution worked once I fixed the references to =COUNTIFS($A:$A,$D2,$B:$B,E$1). Thanks for introducing me to countifs!

Comment: Pleas consider marking the answer below as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS()

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$D2,$B:$B,E$1)
```

[image]

---

But a pivot table may be better suited

[image]